# How to modify icon().abstract.children[0].attributes from the fontawesome-svg-core api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, font-awesome

### The problem:

The [icon()](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/methods/icon) method from the fontawesome-svg-core api sets some default properties for SVG children elements that I need to change.

### What I want to do:

The icon() method generates an object with an "html" property. This property contains (inside an array) a string with the SVG tag that can be used inside some html.

The following code

```
const { icon } = require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core');
const { faVenusMars } = require('@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons');

icon(faVenusMars, { 
    classes: ['fa-2x']
}).html;
```

will generate the following html:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="venus-mars" class="svg-inline--fa fa-venus-mars fa-w-18 fa-2x" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512">
  <path fill="currentColor" d="M564 0h-79c-10.7 ..."></path>
</svg>
```

What I want to do, is to get rid of the `fill="currentColor"` property of the 'path' tag and instead add a `"fill-rule": "evenodd"` property.

### What I tried:

I can see the property I need to change with the `icon(...).abstract` property:

```
[
  {
    "tag": "svg",
    "attributes": {...},
    "children": [
      {
        "tag": "path",
        "attributes": {
          "fill": "currentColor", //  <-- I want to change this!
          "d": "M96…112z"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to modify this property directly, but it doesn't seems to work. So:

- Is there an other method than icon() that I should use?
- Is there some configuration to do in the api to prevent the fill property to be added?
- Is there something else that I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Not sure it is the best one, but it works. I use the [toHtml](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/methods/tohtml) method:

```
const setIcon = (iconRef, config={}) => {
    let myAbstract = icon(iconRef, config).abstract[0];

    myAbstract.children = myAbstract.children.map(child => {

        delete child.attributes.fill;
        child.attributes["fill-rule"] = "evenodd";
        return child;
    });

    let html = toHtml(myAbstract);

    return html;
};
```

Hope it helps someone someday (maybe futur me...)